# Understanding the the construction of a ring from a given sequence and it's properties

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, statistics

The below theorem is given in the Introduction to Mathematical Statistics, Hogg, 8th ed.
I'm a bit confused by the consequence given in the 2nd and 3rd line of the proof.

Why when constructing the ring using the intersection of successive sequences do we set the first ring as the first sequence and successive rings as intersections of the rest? Is there a reason we can't just construct the rings as the successive intersections? ie $R_n = C_n \bigcap C^c_{n+1}$. My guess is it's due to the non-decreasing sequence, but I'm unsure how/why.

Second, why is there a consequence/property from this construction that the rings are disjoint?

An explanation and if possible references/suggestions of further reading to better understanding rings like this would be appreciated. Thank you!
[image: Theorem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the $C_n$ are nondecreasing, your suggestion of $C_n \cap C_{n+1}$ is just $C_n$. The purpose of defining $R_n = C_n \cap C_{n-1}^c$ (note the exponent $c$ in $C_{n-1}^c$ denotes set complement) is so that the $R_n$ are disjoint.

To see this, it may help to draw a picture of $C_1 \subseteq C_2 \subseteq \cdots$ as a sequence of larger and larger concentric circles, and think of $R_1, R_2, \ldots$ as the various "rings"/donuts between consecutive concentric circles. To show this rigorously, note that if $m < n$ then $R_m \subseteq C_m \subseteq C_{n-1}$, but $R_n$ doesn't contain anything in $C_{n-1}$.

The reason why we need disjointness of the $R_n$ is so that we can apply the probability axiom regarding unions of disjoint sets.

Comment: apologies, i've updated the question to reflect the set complement for my suggested ring

Comment: @supremus_58 $C_n \cap C_{n+1}^c$ is the empty set since $C_n \subseteq C_{n+1}$.

Comment: slept on it and it's now better understood. i'd forgotten that the sequence is nested upwards. thanks!